# Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, jsp

So I have this line inside a <% %> mark (JSP), 
I am doing it in SQL Server 2010.

```
'String deleteCmd = "delete from" +'@table_name' + 
"where" + '@idCol' + "=" + rs.getSting(1);'
```

The problem is I can't find anything wrong with this string and the server keeps saying:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure JSP_LIST_TABLE, Line 87
>   Incorrect syntax near 'String deleteCmd = "delete from" +'.

to me it is 100% correct. can anyone see the error ?

Comment: Does it really end with `rs.getSting(1)` or is it `rs.getString(1)`?

Comment: Try adding spaces between all your literals, e.g., `"delete from " + '@TableName' + " where " ... `.  Also consider if the comparison contained in `rs.GetSting(1)` has single quotes around it, which SQL Server will be expecting if the value is anything other than a number.  A helpful exercise might be to print out the `deleteCmd` string and see if it looks like valid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'String deleteCmd = "delete from " +"@"+table_name + " where " + "@"+idCol + "=" + rs.getString(1);'
```

Comment: if i take the (') the code is no longer a string. Because im printing that <% %> so it reads as java code. If i take the (') it becomes T-SQL code

Comment: @PedroCosta I just removed it for better reading. Main improvement is the spaces between the keywords!